# How to compute total price based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

In our website I have a cart table that contains all of the items. Each row has checkboxes. By clicking the checkboxes, it will determine the total price of your cart the you will checkout. At first I don't know  what the title of my question should be as I have 2 problems.

First, when I clicked all the checkboxes, the **Select all** checkbox will be checked, and if I unchecked one, the **Select all** will be unchecked.

Second, is properly getting the total prices based on checkboxes. I am able to get the total price when I tick the checkboxes. It all adds up but if I tick the **Select all** while all other checkboxes are checked, it adds another total which is not right. Please see the demo I uploaded. [Total Price Computation Demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lju9bSImFf_j_0Gw8mVWjy49iK6Fx497/view?usp=sharing)

I'm guessing its because I have put computation in **Select all** also, but I actually run out of ideas on how to achieve this.

Here are my codes

Table

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="select_all"></th>
            <th scope="col">Preview</th>
            <th scope="col">Product</th>
            <th class="text-right" scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th class="text-right" scope="col">Total</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="product-container">
        <?php 
            $cart_items = $cakeOrdering->get_data("SELECT * FROM vw_cart_items ORDER BY cart_itemID DESC");
            if(!empty($cart_items)){
                if(is_array($cart_items) || is_object($cart_items)){
                    foreach($cart_items as $cart_item){
        ?>
        <tr data-id="<?php echo $cart_item['cart_itemID'];?>">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cart_checkbox" class="cart_checkbox"></td>
            <td>
                <img src="../img/cake_uploads/<?php echo $cart_item['image']; ?>" alt="<?php $cart_item['prod_name']; ?>" class="cart_preview">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $cart_item['prod_name']; ?></td>
            <td class="price text-right" data-price="<?php echo $cart_item['price']; ?>">₱&nbsp;<?php echo number_format($cart_item['price'], 2, ".", ","); ?></td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary minus_qty" type="button">-</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="text-center quantity" aria-label="quantity" aria-describedby="quantity" value="<?php echo $cart_item['qty']; ?>" disabled>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary add_qty" type="button">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="total_price text-right" data-total_price="<?php echo $cart_item['total_price']; ?>">₱&nbsp;<?php echo number_format($cart_item['total_price'], 2, ".", ",");?></td>
            <td class="btn-action">
                <a href="" class="text-primary" title="View details"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                <a href="" data-id="<?php echo $cart_item['cart_itemID'];?>" class="text-danger remove" title="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }}} ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
var overall_total = 0;

$('.select_all').on('change', function(){
    $('.cart_checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.total_price').each(function(){
            total_price = $(this).data('total_price');
            overall_total = overall_total + parseFloat(total_price);
        });
    }else{
        $('.total_price').each(function(){
            total_price = $(this).data('total_price');
            overall_total = overall_total - parseFloat(total_price);
        });
    }
    $('.overall_total').text(formatToCurrency(overall_total));
});

$(".cart_checkbox").change(function(){
    var total_price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.total_price').data('total_price');

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        overall_total = overall_total + parseFloat(total_price);
    }else{
        overall_total = overall_total - parseFloat(total_price);
    }
    $('.overall_total').text(formatToCurrency(overall_total));
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue you can check if the *length* of total checkboxes and *checked* checkboxes are not equal depending this check/uncheck your select_all checkbox .

Now, for next issue i have move whole calculation part inside different *function* so whenever you need to total you can call this function and then loop through only checked trs row and change total values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.select_all').on('change', function() {
  $('.cart_checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  sum(); //call this 
});

$(".cart_checkbox").change(function() {
  var total_length = $(".cart_checkbox").length;
  var checked_length = $(".cart_checkbox:checked").length
  //check if length less then total
  if (checked_length < total_length) {
    $('.select_all').prop('checked', false); //uncheck..
  } else {
    $('.select_all').prop('checked', true); //check
  }
  sum(); //call this
})

function sum() {

  var overall_total = 0;
  //loop through only checked trs..
  $(".cart_checkbox:checked").closest("tr").find('.total_price').each(function() {
    total_price = $(this).data('total_price');
    overall_total = overall_total + parseFloat(total_price);
  })
  $('.overall_total').text(overall_total); //add your format fn
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="select_all"></th>
      <th scope="col">Preview</th>
      <th scope="col">Product</th>
      <th class="text-right" scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th class="text-right" scope="col">Total</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="product-container">

    <tr data-id="1">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cart_checkbox" class="cart_checkbox"></td>
      <td>
        <img src="../img/cake_uploads/<?php echo $cart_item['image']; ?>" alt="<?php $cart_item['prod_name']; ?>" class="cart_preview">
      </td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td class="price text-right" data-price="34">₱&nbsp;34</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary minus_qty" type="button">-</button>
          </div>
          <input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="text-center quantity" aria-label="quantity" aria-describedby="quantity" value="<?php echo $cart_item['qty']; ?>" disabled>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary add_qty" type="button">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_price text-right" data-total_price="74">₱&nbsp;74</td>
      <td class="btn-action">
        <a href="" class="text-primary" title="View details"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="" data-id="1" class="text-danger remove" title="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-id="2">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cart_checkbox" class="cart_checkbox"></td>
      <td>
        <img src="../img/cake_uploads/<?php echo $cart_item['image']; ?>" alt="<?php $cart_item['prod_name']; ?>" class="cart_preview">
      </td>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td class="price text-right" data-price="34">₱&nbsp;34</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary minus_qty" type="button">-</button>
          </div>
          <input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="text-center quantity" aria-label="quantity" aria-describedby="quantity" value="<?php echo $cart_item['qty']; ?>" disabled>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary add_qty" type="button">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_price text-right" data-total_price="742">₱&nbsp;742</td>
      <td class="btn-action">
        <a href="" class="text-primary" title="View details"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="" data-id="2" class="text-danger remove" title="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-id="3">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="cart_checkbox" class="cart_checkbox"></td>
      <td>
        <img src="../img/cake_uploads/<?php echo $cart_item['image']; ?>" alt="<?php $cart_item['prod_name']; ?>" class="cart_preview">
      </td>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td class="price text-right" data-price="343">₱&nbsp;343</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary minus_qty" type="button">-</button>
          </div>
          <input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="text-center quantity" aria-label="quantity" aria-describedby="quantity" value="<?php echo $cart_item['qty']; ?>" disabled>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary add_qty" type="button">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="total_price text-right" data-total_price="743">₱&nbsp;743</td>
      <td class="btn-action">
        <a href="" class="text-primary" title="View details"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="" data-id="3" class="text-danger remove" title="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<span class="overall_total"></span>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much.  At first I have an Idea that computation should be on separate function. Just don't know how to apply it. Plus, I would have never think of this line `$(".cart_checkbox:checked").closest("tr").find('.total_price').each(function() {});` I have no idea I can loop through _checked_ checkboxes.
Thanks again.

Comment: `computation should be on separate function..` I put that whole part in function because you need to use that code at mutliple places so instead of writing them mutliple times you can simply call function.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `overall_total = 0` inside your `$('.select_all').on('change'`  and it should work. And remove else portion.

```
$('.select_all').on('change', function(){
    
    $('.cart_checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    // reset total value to 0 because in below every product values are being fetched and summed up.
    overall_total = 0;

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.total_price').each(function(){
            total_price = $(this).data('total_price');
            overall_total = overall_total + parseFloat(total_price);
        });
    }
    //else{
    //    $('.total_price').each(function(){
    //        total_price = $(this).data('total_price');
    //        overall_total = overall_total - parseFloat(total_price);
    //    });
    //}

    $('.overall_total').text(formatToCurrency(overall_total));
});
```

Comment: This does work on not subtracting the total. But if the select all is checked, it still adds the total price on top of the total checked checkboxes. But thanks, I get the logic.